# Minifying bower_components js files

Tags: javascript

I am currently using spoeken's gulp workflow (https://github.com/spoeken/gulp-craftcms). Everything works well in development, however, when it comes to production, I can't seem to concat/minify my `bower_components` dependencies, into one file.

I currently have a `public/resources/js/app.min.js`, however, my `bower_component` dependencies are sitting in `app/resources/bower_components`.

How do you go about minifying my dependencies into one file?

Here's what I have in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "craftgulp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    ""
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.2.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "gsap": "^1.19.1",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss",
        "assets/fonts/bootstrap/*",
        "assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "scrollmagic": {
      "main": [
        "./scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js",
        "./scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js",
        "./scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js",
        "./scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/jquery.ScrollMagic.js"
      ]
    },
    "gsap": {
      "main": [
        "./src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js",
        "./src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js",
        "./src/uncompressed/jquery.gsap.js"
      ]
    },
    "slick-carousel": {
      "main": [
        "./slick/slick.min.js",
        "./slick/slick.css",
        "./slick/slick-theme.css"
      ]
    },
    "waypoints": {
      "main": [
        "./lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to define them in [the Gulp file build uglify task](https://github.com/spoeken/gulp-craftcms/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L97).